# Any way to simplify a program I wrote? (beginning programmer)

Tags: java, math

I'm beginning in Java programming in college (Comp Sci major with no real background in programming) and in my spare time I've made a program that calculates the missing side of a right triangle given 2 known sides. I used virtually all techniques and methods we've learned so far to make this program and I just wanted to know if there were any ways to simplify the program or any of the lines I've included in the program. Thanks for the help.

```
Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        String hIf;
        String unit;
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
        /*The purpose of this program is to just ask for 2 sides of a right triangle to calculate the third side,
        or, in other words, this program evaluates the pythagorean theorem, a^2+b^2=c^2
         */
        System.out.println("This program will calculate one missing side length of a right triangle.");
        System.out.println("Please input the units you will be using.");
            unit = e.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Will you be calculating the length of the hypotenuse? Type yes or no.");
            hIf = e.nextLine();
        while(!(hIf.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")||hIf.equalsIgnoreCase("no")))
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid answer. Please type yes or no.");
                    hIf = e.nextLine();
            }
        if (hIf.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            System.out.println("To calculate the length of the hypotenuse, you will need to input the length of the two other sides.");
            System.out.println("Please input the length of side A.");
                    a = e.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please input the length of side B.");
                b = e.nextDouble();
                c = Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
                c = Math.sqrt(c);

        }
        else
            {
            System.out.println("To calculate the length of the missing side, you will need to input the length of the hypotenuse, and the other known side.");
            System.out.println("Please input the length of the hypotenuse. Note that this is the longest possible side of the triangle.");
                c = e.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please input the length of the other side.");
                a = e.nextDouble();
             while(!(c>a))
                {
                    System.out.print("The inputted hypotenuse is impossible. Note that the hypotenuse must be the longest side.");
                    System.out.println(" Please input the hypotenuse again.");
                    c = e.nextDouble();
                }
                b = Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2);
                b = Math.sqrt(b);

        }
System.out.println("Side A: " + String.format("%.2f", a) + " " + unit);
System.out.println("Side B: " + String.format("%.2f", b) + " " + unit);
System.out.println("Side C: " + String.format("%.2f", c) + " " + unit);
```

Comment: If this code is already working as you expect, it might be better to post to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is a dedicated exchange for reviewing code and improving it.  The code must be fully functional though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! What pieces of the code do you want to simplify or do you want to fix how it looks?

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is that your I/O code and your actual program logic are intermingled. I would extract the program logic into its own classes and methods, and leave the I/O stuff in `main` (or its own class as well.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Perhaps consider making your variable names meaningful. I wouldn’t know what `e` or `b` etc is without having to check.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! I appreciate it. I hadn't learned methods at this time but I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fairly new myself so take my advice with a grain of salt. But speaking from an aesthetic view, I think the code in you if and else statements can be moved into their own separate functions. Also, you can look into having a basic GUI which controls the "yes" input so you can have a definite value to check. I learned in one of my classes that you should avoid using string comparisons when possible.